# Show Modal on app screen load automatically in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I used [Modal_bottom_sheet 2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) to make a modal. And I have some code:

```
                GestureDetector(
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                    onTap: () => {
                          CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                            expand: true,
                            context: context,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                            builder: (context) => Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                MyWidget(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        }),
```

The code above is render an `Icon(Icons.arrow_upward)`. When user `onTap` on this icon, my Cupertino BottomSheet will call.

But now I want the Modal will auto call without `onTap`.

I tried this code below but it not work

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
        expand: true,
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyWidget(),        
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

How can I show the Cupertino BottomSheet without `onTap()` on the icon ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap cupertinoShowMode method inb `SetState` function. Instead you can create a function which display the bottom sheet and call this function from `initState` method.

##### call `displaySheet` method inside `initState` function.

```dart
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     displaySheet(); 
   });
  
}
```

```dart
void displaySheet(){
 CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
        expand: true,
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyWidget(),        
          ],
        ),
      )
}
```